# Firebase Pubsub Functions does not invoke

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to write the function to trigger whenever data is published from my device. I have 2 project thats used the same google email (Of course same GCP account).

1. Project A: I use IoT Core, and PubSub. My device publish data to `IoTCore`
2. Project B: It is firebase project that I use to deploy my functions.

My function looks like:

```
exports.telemetryReceive = functions.pubsub.topic('mytopic').onPublish( (message) ==> {...}).
```

When I try to use my device to publish data to `PubSub` (of course i my data is published properly to IoTCore, and I could see it on `Cloud PubSub`), but when I try to inspect the function executed log on firebase, I could not see my function executing.

Please anyone kindly help me to figure out how to fix the problem

Comment: Is your snippet copied word for word from your application? There's a typo in "onPublish". If so, can you try invoking the function via command as documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events#access_the_pubsub_message_payload)?

Comment: ah sorry, i wrote snippet manually, not copied from my application. As i described, my function was deployed successfully to firebase CF, and I still get the message that i published by using "gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions" command, but my function on firebase does not fire :(

Comment: As an alternative, would you be open to trying out [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#sample_code) (not through the Firebase Console)? I believe Firebase Functions w/ Pub/Sub triggers is still in beta, so testing the integration with Cloud Functions might help further debug the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, but sorry, i could not understand clearly your idea. How could i try out the Cloud Functions (not through the Firebase Console) ?

Comment: From the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com), same as IoT Core & Pub/Sub, you can deploy a [Cloud Function](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions) which is different than Firebase Functions. Here's a [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart-nodejs) to get you started. The only difference would be using "Cloud Pub/Sub" as a trigger, rather than HTTP.